# integral from 0 to 0.25 of arcsin(sqrt(x))?

Tags: calculus, integration

have this due in class in a few days, i tried the indefinite integral first, which wolfram says is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=integral+arcsin%28rootx%29+dx)

which i can get.

but when i try the definite integral, i'm not getting anything close to what wolfram says the answer is, think i'm just screwing up limits of integration. any help would be appreciated

sorry for the question not having proper latex or whatever its called, i don't know how to do that

Comment: Note that $\arcsin(\sqrt{0.25})=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \arcsin\sqrt x=u\implies \sqrt x=\sin u\implies x=\sin^2u\implies dx=2\sin u\cos u\ du=\sin2u\ du$

$$I=\int\arcsin\sqrt x\ dx=\int u\cdot2\sin2u\ du$$

Using [Integration By Parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html),

$$I=2u\cdot\int\sin2u\ du-\int\left(\frac{du}{du}\cdot\int\sin2u\ du\right)du$$

$$=2u\cdot\frac{-\cos2u}2+\int\frac{\cos2u}2du=-u\cos2u+\frac{\sin2u}4 $$

Now, $\displaystyle x=0\implies u=0;x=\frac14\implies u=\arcsin\frac12=\frac\pi6$ (As  André  has observed)

Comment: thanks for the reply lab. so the final answer you are getting is pi/6? wolfram says the answer is 0.0856067. sorry, its a bit hard for me to follow what the answer is, especially since our prof asked us to do a u-sub with sqrt(x) rather than the entire function.

Comment: @steven, just put the values of $u$. Observe that for $u=0$ the integral reduces to $0$

Comment: sorry man, i'm just absolutely lost here. the final answer of which you should be evaluating is this? http://puu.sh/7lgdL.png at u=pi/6? that still doesn't give the right answer

Comment: $$-\frac\pi6\cos\frac\pi3+\frac{\sin\frac\pi3}4$$  $$=-\frac\pi6\cdot\frac12+\frac14\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}2??$$

Comment: yeah, that's -.04529.. and so on. that's not the answer that wolfram is giving.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0+to+0.25+arcsin%28rootx%29+dx

Comment: @steven, have you understood the method applied?

Comment: sort of. our prof asked us to do a u-sub with sqrt(x), then IBP, then a trig substitution with the integral that comes out of IBP. i can follow your work, as far as getting upto what you just posted in the last reply 12 minutes ago, but evaluating that isn't what wolfram says the answer is, so that's where i'm confused

Comment: also in your original reply, you used the 2sinucosu = sin2u identity. but in moving it back into the integrand, you wrote 2sin2u. where does that 2 multiplier come from?

Answer (score 2):

Integration yields

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-p\cos2p + \frac{1}{2}\sin2p \right) + C,$$

where $p = \arcsin\sqrt{x}$, i.e $\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}$.

So breaking it down further to $x$ terms we have:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-(1- 2x)\arcsin\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\smash[b]{x -x²}} \right) + C.$$

So putting $d$ on the limit we have

$$-\frac{π}{12} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}.$$